# Is Base64 standardized?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, base64

In the company that I work, we have class to convert to and from Base64 string. When I first saw the code, I asked why don´t use the Convert.ToBase64String that comes with .NET?

Then I modified the method body to just call Convert.ToBase64String, but it don´t generate the same string.

I tried using ASCII, UTF8, Unicode and UTF32.

I dont remember exactly but I think that ASCII generates a string with the same length but some chars different, and others Enconding generates bigger strings.

Maybe our implementation was wrong, but I found a JavaScript implementations that matches ours.

Isn´t Base64 portable?

**Edit:** I found this at Wikipedia, but I don´t know if it was the cause http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history

**Edit2**: I mentioned encodings because we are converting a string to another. Then I need to firstly convert my original string to a byte array using some encoding

Comment: I thought it was, so I'm watching this with interest.

Comment: It is, sounds like maybe they are using a custom implementation for some reason. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648

Comment: Converting a sequence of bytes to a Base64 string doesn't involve ASCII, UTF-8 or Unicode.

Comment: @dtb I forgot to say, the method that we use converts a string to another, not a byte array.

Comment: Some code would be very helpfull :)

Comment: @Fujiy: There you have your answer: Base64 is standardized; your custom method is not.

Comment: @dtb I understood the opposite. If I convert a byte array to Base64 I still get different results since exists different implementations as mentioned by Serge(RFC 3548 and 4648) and Wikipedia

Comment: @Fujiy: The fact that an RFC is obsoleted by a newer one doens't neccesarily means that the standard was modified. It may simply mean that the content was reformatted, incorporated into other texts,...

Comment: @Serge-appTranslator wikipedia lists 13 different implementations

Comment: So what? The existence of 13 or even 13000 implementations doesn't mean that the standard significanlty changed from RFC x to RFC y.

Comment: @Serge-appTranslator the problem is that I can´t encode a string using base64 in a technology(C#) and decode at another (JavaScript). Or using different implementations is same technology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 10 different implementations. They mostly differ by the char for index 62 and 63.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history

Answer (score 10):

RFC 3548. No, wait! There's a newer one: [RFC 4648](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt). (Thanks dtb!)

BTW, you seem to be mixing base64, which turns any binary stream into an ASCII stream and character encodings, which are totally different concepts. You may want to read [this introduction article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) about encodings.